# UIImagePickerViewController Cannot activate iOS11 's album permission BUT can load Photo and Videos

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

**why UIPickerView Can load photo and videos without iOS11's permission?
It seems no any permission alert popover.**

iOS11 - GM
xcode9 beta 4

New blank app:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     UIImagePickerController *vc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
     UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     picker.delegate = self;
     picker.allowsEditing = YES;
     picker.sourceType = sourceType;
     vc.delegate = self;
     [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

it can access photo library easily without any alert , you even can load the photo to set the background.
is this a system lever bug? or I do some wrong?

ps: set up info.plist with below already:

`NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL2GW.png)

Comment: First delete the app and reinstall it and check

Comment: Please edit your question, it is UIImagePickerController not UIPickerView

Answer (score 0):

It is ask only one time for permission. If once you allow it then you will not get that alert every time. So, If you want to check it again then delete your app and reinstall it and you will find alert asking for permission !

Comment: I mean no alert here, I can't not choose allow or not because no alert view pop up , but can access the photo library. It is new blank app.